# Show UITableView Overflow?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a UIView transparent over it. It looks really cool. The fact that you can see beyond the UITableView.

My problem is that if I make the UITableView extend to the end of the UIView, you can't scroll to see the last one.

I tried adding a cell but the sizes don't match up and it looks kinda funny. What's the best solution to this?

Thanks,
Coulton

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As table views are scroll views, you can give your table view a bottom inset, which works like bottom padding to push your cells some distance off the bottom edge of your table view.

```
CGFloat heightOfYourTabBar = 50;
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, heightOfYourTabBar, 0);

[self.tableView setContentInset:insets];
[self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:insets];
```

The region of your table view that shows under your tab bar will continue to be visible, but the "bottom" of your cells is pushed up to the top. This way, you can scroll all the way to your last cell without it being obscured by your tab bar.

Scroll views and content insets are covered in the [Configuring The Scroll View Content Size, Content Inset, And Scroll Indicators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW14) section of Apple's Scroll View Programming Guide for iOS. There's an example for the Photos app, which is exactly the pattern you'll mimic for your app by adding insets.

Answer (score 3):

Have not tried that myself, but that may work:

Create a (blank) `UIView` with appropriate height and set it to table's `tableFooterView` properties - so it will appear under all your cells and make the last cell appear above your toolbar.

Comment: This works, but the scroll indicator will dip itself into the tab bar. A better idea is to give the table view a content and scroll indicator inset, so the padding affects both the cells and the scroll indicator. (Well you *could* add the footer view and then create an inset with its height, but I prefer to be a little consistent...)

Comment: Yes, your solution is much better indeed )